# Let V be a set of given matrices. Prove that V is a group under matrix multiplication, and find all subgroups of V.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $V=\left\lbrace A_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},
A_2=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},
A_3=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},
A_4=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}
\right\rbrace $. Prove that $V$ is a group under matrix multiplication, and find all subgroups of $V$.

I tried and got proof that $V$ is a group under matrix multiplication . So, let's skip to the my second question.

Let $M\subseteq V$ and $M=\lbrace A_2,A_3,A_4 \rbrace$, since $e_V = I = A_1$ is trivial subgroup of V. We'll show that $M$ is a subgroup of $V$. Consider the multiplication of every two matrices in $M$. Well, since $A_2A_3^{-1}, A_2A_4^{-1}, \text{ and } A_3A_4^{-1} \in M$,   $M$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $V$.

But, how do I find the other non-trivial subgroups of $V$? Thanks for your help and attention.

Comment: Are you familiar with Klein's [Vierergruppe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group)?  $M$ is not a subgroup since it does not contain the identity

Comment: You would also need $A_2A_2^{-1}$ in $M$, in other words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-trivial proper subgroups of $V$ are $\{A_1, A_2\}$, $\{A_1,A_3\}$, and $\{A_1,A_4\}$.

Any subgroup must contain the identity element $A_1$.

Comment: oh okay got it.

Comment: but, what about $\lbrace A_1,A_2,A_3\rbrace$ etc ?

Comment: if $A_2$ and $A_3$ are in the subgroup, then so is $A_2A_3=A_4$; also, the order of a subgroup must divide the order of the group, so, since the order of $V$ is $4$, the order of a subgroup could be $1, 2, $ or $4$, but not $3$

Comment: Are $\lbrace A_1,A_2,A_3 \rbrace, \lbrace A_1,A_2,A_4 \rbrace, \lbrace A_1,A_3,A_4 \rbrace, \lbrace A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4 \rbrace$ not include nontrivial subgroup of $V$ ?

Comment: Oh, i see. Since $Ord(V)=4$, then $\lbrace A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4 \rbrace$, or $V$ itself be subgroup non trivial of $V$, right?

Comment: As I said, you can't have a subgroup of $V$ with $3$ elements; of course, $V$ is a subgroup, but not a proper subgroup, of $V$

Comment: well, got it. thanks for correction